# wget: force no default certificates

Tags: wget, ssl

I'm having trouble with verification of custom server SSL certificates and wget.

```
 wget -O- --ca-certificate=myservercert.pem https://www.google.com
```

This should fail but does not, as `wget` does somehow also include the "default trusted" certificates from `/etc/ssl`. With `curl`, the same works as expected.

How can I have two mutually authenticated SSL points with **no** trust defaults?

Answer (score 2):

The answer turns out to depend on which SSL library wget is linked with. It might also depend on the version, but between wget 1.13 and 1.15 the behavior hasn't changed.

#### If wget is linked with GnuTLS (e.g. Debian)

Wget can read certificates from a file or from the files in a directory. To turn off all default trusted CAs (in `/etc/ssl/certs`), pass both `--ca-certificate` and `--ca-directory`.

```
wget -O- --ca-directory=/empty --ca-certificate=myservercert.pem https://www.google.com
```

(Create `/empty` to avoid an error message, but wget keeps going even if the directory doesn't exist anyway.)

#### If wget is linked with OpenSSL (e.g. Ubuntu)

Wget unconditionally checks the certificates in the default location for OpenSSL (`/usr/lib/ssl/certs` on Ubuntu, determined at `./configure` time by the `--openssldir` option). The file and directory specified on the command line, if any, are checked in addition to that. There is no option to disable the default location.

The default location is checked because wget calls the `SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths` function from OpenSSL unconditionally. You can use [`LD_PRELOAD`](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/simple-ld-preload-tutorial/) to nullify the call.

```
$ cat no_openssl_default_verify_paths.c 
int SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths(void *ctx) {
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o no_openssl_default_verify_paths.so no_openssl_default_verify_paths.c
$ wget -nv -O /dev/null https://www.google.com 
2015-05-04 14:31:02 URL:https://www.google.fr/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=hmZHVa_DD5Tu8wex3IC4BQ [18613] -> "/dev/null" [1]
$ LD_PRELOAD=~/no_openssl_default_verify_paths.so wget -nv -O /dev/null https://www.google.com
ERROR: cannot verify www.google.com's certificate, issued by ‘/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.google.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

Comment: Does that command actually work (i.e. refuse to load the page) for you? What version of wget do you have? I have tried on both CentOS and Arch Linux and both load the page happily.

Comment: @je843 Debian wheezy, wget 1.13.3. The page loads with just `--ca-certificate` but not if I also pass `--ca-directory`.

Comment: OK so that is either bug in new wget or debian specific configuration/patch. I'll try to contact the wget developers.

Comment: @je843 I just tried with wget 1.15 on Ubuntu 14.04 and I observe the same behavior as you. It turns out to be due not to the version of wget, nor to the distribution in itself, but to which SSL library wget is compiled against. See my edited answer.